# What causes the "QTimeLine already running" message in PySide?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

As stated in the question, I'm getting this warning message in my terminal when I try to simply animate a circle using QGraphicsItemAnimation's setPosAt() function, and I'm quite puzzled as to the origin of this warning. My code:

```
def animate(self):

    # moves item to location smoothly in one second
    def animate_to(t,item,x,y):
        # used to animate an item in specific ways
        animation = QtGui.QGraphicsItemAnimation()

        # create a timeline (1 sec here)
        timeline = QtCore.QTimeLine(1000)
        timeline.setFrameRange(0,100)   # 100 steps

        #item should at 'x,y' by time 't'
        animation.setPosAt(t,QtCore.QPointF(x,y))
        animation.setItem(item)             # animate this item
        animation.setTimeLine(timeline)     # with this duration/steps

        return animation

    self.animations.append(animate_to(1,self.c1,150,150))

    [ animation.timeLine().start() for animation in self.animations ]

    self.animator.start(1000)
```

What confuses me the most is the fact that this warning goes away when I comment out the last line in the previous section - which from my understanding is related to the QTimer and not the QTimeLine itself. For reference, here is the only other code dealing with the QTimer:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
    self.setupUi(self)

          ...

    self.animator = QtCore.QTimer()
    self.animator.timeout.connect(self.animate)

    self.animate()
```

Any thoughts on the origin of this warning or any possible fixes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code indentation is a little off (top line should be un-indented?), so I'll summarize your code in words just to confirm I understand what is happening.

You call `self.animate()`. This method creates an animation, and appends it to a list, `self.animations`. You iterate over this list and start the animations. You start a timer (with a 1 second timeout) which calls `self.animate()`.

The problem arises because `self.animations` grows by one element each time you call `self.animate()`. So the old animation instances are still in the list the next time the method is called. You are iterating over the entire list to start the animations, so you are calling `animator.timeLine().start()` multiple times on a animation.

Removing the call to the timer prevents the `self.animation()` method from running more than once, so you don't ever run into the problem when you comment out that line.

Comment: Thanks! You were right. In my case, since the list 'animations' is updated with new animations every time the function is called, I simply cleared the list at the beginning of every iteration using:
    del self.animations[:]

Comment: @estebro You might want to consider removing the animation from the list when it has finished by connecting to the `finished()` signal of the timeline. That way you don't risk having your animation object prematurely deleted (for instance if the next iteration happens to run just before the animation finishes). You are probably Ok, but your at risk of this race condition given that the length of the animation is the same as the length of the QTimer. I'll update my post with an example.

Comment: Actually, I won't add any more to my post because it gets quite complicated. If you go down the route I just siggested, you still risk calling `start()` twice on a given timeline, so you would need to put in a condition in your method which only started timelines that had not yet run (or had only just been created). Something to think about for the future anyway!

Comment: Thanks again for the suggestions. I had considered keeping track of the animations which had yet to be started so as to only call start() on those - as you suggest in your second comment. I would appreciate the example if you have the time. Thanks either way though!

Comment: @estebro I'll leave it to you as an exercise :) if you run into problems, feel free to post a new question on stack overflow!